# How do I check that a python value is an instance of a numpy dtype?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, isinstance

How do I check that a given value can be stored in a `numpy` array?

E.g.:

```
import numpy as np
np.array(["a","b"])
==> array(['a', 'b'], dtype='|S1')
np.array(["a","b"]) == 1
> __main__:1: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
==> False
np.array(["a","b"]) == "a"
==> array([ True, False], dtype=bool)
```

I want a function `np_isinstance` which would do this:

```
np_isinstance("a", np.array(["a","b"]).dtype)
==> True
np_isinstance(1, np.array(["a","b"]).dtype)
==> False
np_isinstance("a", np.array([1,2,3]).dtype)
==> False
np_isinstance(1, np.array([1,2,3]).dtype)
==> True
```

So far I managed to come up with

```
def np_isinstance(o,dt):
    return np.issubdtype(np.array([o]).dtype, dt)
```

but this seems wrong because it allocates an `array` on each invocation.

One might hope that [numpy.can_cast(from, totype)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.can_cast.html) would do the job, but, alas,

```
np.can_cast("a",np.dtype("O"))
> TypeError: did not understand one of the types; 'None' not accepted
```

Comment: Allocating an array every time isn't a big deal. It's probably cheaper than you think (or rather, everything else is probably more expensive than you think, so allocation is cheap in relative terms).

Answer (score 0):

When I'm understanding correctly, that the whole numpy array is always of a certain type and there cannot be mixed items in the array I would suggest doing:

```
isinstance(my_array, np.ndarray)`
```

That's what I'm doing in my unittest:

`assert isinstance(groups, np.ndarray)`

while in my production code i do this

```
groups = [-1, -1, 0, 2]
groups = np.asarray(g, dtype=np.uint8)
```

---

Edit: I misunderstood the question at first. You want to check if a ceratin variable can be inserted in the array. Well let's try this then:

```
def is_var_allowed(x):
    try:
        x = np.uint8(x)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

def main():
    my_arr = np.ones((5,), dtype=np.uint8))
    x = 7
    if is_var_allowed(x):
       my_arr.put(3, x)
```

This will result in an array `[1 1 1 7 1]`. One could generalize this by giving the function `is_var_allowed` also a dtype as parameter like this:

```
def is_var_allowed(x, func):
    try:
        x = func(x)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

def main():
    my_uint_arr = np.ones((5,), dtype=np.uint8))
    x = 7
    if is_var_allowed(x, np.uint8):
       my_uint8_arr.put(3, x)

    my_char_arr = np.char.array((5,1))
    y = "Hallo"
    if is_var_allowed(y, np.char)
        my_char_arr[:] = y
```

Comment: Oh I think I misunderstood your question. You try to check if a value can be put in the array. Well why dont you try to create another varible out of it: np.uint8(my_var). You can guard this with a try/except to see if it fails or not. if not you can put it into the array. np.uint8() will fail when presenting a string

Comment: Still no go. You are assuming numeric dtype.

Comment: When using a a function as a second parameter you could generalize it

Comment: Where do I get the `func` for `is_var_allowed`?

Comment: I have a `dtype` object. How do I "generalize" it to your function? Most important, how is your version better than mine?

Comment: How about this:
`if a.dtype == var.dtype`. You would have to try to cast your variable to a numpy variable such as np.char and np.uint8 and then you could use this check. If the cast fails it is definitely not able to be put in the array if it does and the dtype fits the dtype of the array you can put it in.

Comment: thanks, I already found the answer: [numpy.can_cast(from, totype, casting = 'safe')](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.can_cast.html).

Answer (score 0):

I did not know how to judge directly, as there are so many [dtype in numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/arrays.dtypes.html), instead, you could use the following function to judge:

```
def np_isinstance(value, np_data):
    """
    This function for 1D np_data
    """
    flag = False
    try:
        tmp = np_data[0] + value
        flag = True
    except:
        pass
    return flag
```

Comment: what if the array `np_data` is empty? what if I do not have an array, just dtype? how is this better than my version?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have missed these, I will keeping thinking another way.

Comment: @sds, But for your answer, check **o = 1.1**, "dt=np.int64", "np_isinstance(o,dt)", do you expect float numbers should not insert to np.int64 arrays or int64 numbers should not be insert to float arrays?

Answer (score 0):

`can_cast` replicates your test cases:

```
In [213]: np.can_cast(type("a"), np.array(["a","b"]).dtype)
Out[213]: True
In [214]: np.can_cast(type(1), np.array(["a","b"]).dtype)
Out[214]: False
In [215]: np.can_cast(type("a"), np.array([1,2,3]).dtype)
Out[215]: False
In [217]: np.can_cast(type(1), np.array([1,2,3]).dtype)
Out[217]: True
In [219]: np.can_cast(type(1), np.dtype("O"))
Out[219]: True
In [220]: np.can_cast(type("a"), np.dtype("O"))
Out[220]: True
```

Note that I'm matching a `type` with a `dtype`.